# I am trying to update ownerID field of task from the text field.but getting error

Tags: apex, trigger

> Apex trigger TaskCreate caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: TaskCreate: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject:
>   Trigger.TaskCreate: line 23, column 1

```
Trigger TaskCreate on Task (after insert, after update)
    {
        If(Trigger.IsAfter)
        {
            If(trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
            {
                List<Task>Tasklist=new List<Task>();

                for(Task ts : trigger.new)
                {                if(ts.Status == 'Completed' )
                    {
                        system.debug('ts.Status------'+ts.Status);
                        system.debug('tss------'+ts);

                        Task td = new task();

                        td.WhoId=ts.WhoId;
                        td.Status='Not Started';
                        td.Subject=ts.Next_Step__c;
                        td.ActivityDate=ts.Next_Step_Due_Date__c;
                        td.Inside_Sales_Reps__c=ts.Inside_Sales_Reps__c;                            
                        td.OwnerId=[Select Id from User where Name =:ts.Next_Step_Owner__c].Id;                                                                                                   
                        Tasklist.add(td);
                        system.debug('Tasklist------'+Tasklist);
                    } 
                }if(Tasklist.size()>0){
                    try{
                        insert Tasklist;
                    }
                    catch(exception e){
                        system.debug('---e---'+e);
                    }
                }            
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Did you attempt to search the error message here. Lots of duplicate questions and answers that are easily found

Comment: Please do not do any DML in a loop.

Comment: Please check if the value present in Next_Step_Owner__c field actually exist in your org if not then you will get this error

Comment: I have tested your code and it is working fine for me without giving any error

Answer (score 0):

Bad Practice is being followed here.
**DO NOT USE QUERY INSIDE LOOP. THINIK OF TRIGGER AS BULK DATA INSERTION AND NOT SINGLE RECORD**.

First Make a change to that using map something like this.

```
Map<String, String> mapOfNextStepOwnerIdAndUserId = new Map<String,String>();
Set<Sring> ownerId = new Set<String>();
for(Objec ojb: trigger.new){
     ownerIdSet.add(obj.yourNameField);
   }

 for(User u: [select id from User where Name IN :ownerIdSet]){
       mapOfNextStepOwnerIdAndUserId .put(u.Name, u.Id);
    }
```

And then instead of querying there in loop. Use mapOfNextStepOwnerIdAndUserId .get('yourFieldName');